# PostgreSQL setup The System cannot find the path specified

Tags: postgresql, installation, psql

Hey I follow this guide: https://codeforgeek.com/postgres-with-nodejs-windows/

But I don't even get prompt for a password, it just give me this error?

[image]

Should I type in something on the lines?